# Passing data from mongodb to my front end application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mean-stack

I have a MongoDB on a web server and I have a Mean stack web application.  Within the MongoDB, I have a bunch of data that I want to pass to my web application.  I have looked into options, but I'm a little unsure as to which route to take to make this happen. I have considered using socket.io to set up a listener on my web server to open up a connection with my DB, and then making an API call or direct DB connection to return my data.

I should add that my app is based on the mean.io boilerplate code.

My question is where within my stack do I need to put the socket.io code?

Would it be wise to include the socket.io code at the root of my application or only in the packages/modules that require the data to be passed from my web server to my application?

And finally, is socket.io even the preferred route to take? Is there another method to achieve this that makes more sense such as express.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use socket.io unless you want real-time constant, persistant streaming of information from your database to your front-end.

First in your express app, connect to the db with `https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native`. Then, you can just set up a JSON endpoint route for the data to get sent to. Then the client webpage that needs the data simply sends an XHR request to the JSON page.

EDIT: OP does want to use socket.io.

If you want to use socket.io, you have to include it on both the server and the client.

Server-side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
// socket.io
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
// handling socket.io requests
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  log.info('new connection.');
  socket.emit('data', {/** whatever data you need to send **/});
  socket.on('disconnect', (e) => {
    log.info('user disconnected.');
  });
});
```

Client-side:

Be sure to include socket.io in the html file (get it from the website). Then, in your client-side js:

```
const socket = io();
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to server.');
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('disconnected.');
});
socket.on('data', (data) => {
    // this is where you receive the data
    // do something with your data
});
```

Comment: real time persistent streaming is actually a feature that I need, so it sounds like socket.io is the correct route I want to take

Comment: I appreciate this, it makes things more clear.  The data I want to pass to my front end application is actually on a separate mongodb server by itself.  I would need to somehow make a connection to that server from a client-side file with a call like such -- var socket = io.connect('server address here'); 
My issue is where this connection fits into the stack I am using

Comment: No, socket.io needs to connect to the express web server, not to the mongo db server. The express web server is then connected to the Mongo db server. Using the NodeJS API in the link in my answer, you need to fetch the data from the db, and pass it to the socket.io, via a callback.

Comment: ohhhhhhh okay that was just what I needed. You filled the void in my head. thank you, wizard

Answer (score 1):

You should create a route in Express and then, request that route from your angular SPA with an http module, like $http ou Restangular.
Take a look at this article https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application